# Theano row/column wise subtraction

Tags: numpy, matrix, vectorization, theano

`X` is an n by d matrix, `W` is an m by d matrix, for every row in `X` I want to compute the squared Euclidean distance with every row in `W`, so the results will be an n by m matrix.

If there's only one row in `W`, this is easy

```
x = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False, False])()
w = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False])()
z = tensor.sum((x-w)**2, axis=1)
fn = theano.function([x, w], z)
print fn([[1,2,3], [2,2,2]], [2,2,2])
# [ 2.  0.]
```

What do I do when `W` is a matrix (in Theano)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist)

Long answer, if you don't have scipy, is to broadcast subtract and then norm by axis 0.

`np.linalg.norm(X[:,:,None]-W[:,None,:], axis=0)`

Really long answer, of you have an ancient version of numpy without a vecorizable `linalg.norm` (i.e. you're using Abaqus) is

`np.sum((X[:,:,None]-W[:,None,:])**2, axis=0).__pow__(0.5)`

**Edit by OP**
In Theano we can make `X` and `W` both 3d matrices and make the corresponding axes broadcastable like

```
x = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False, True, False])()
w = tensor.TensorType("float64", [True, False, False])()

z = tensor.sum((x-w)**2, axis=2)

fn = theano.function([x, w], z)
print fn([[[0,1,2]], [[1,2,3]]], [[[1,1,1], [2,2,2]]])
# [[ 2.  5.]
#  [ 5.  2.]]
```

Comment: thank you, actually I was asking for an implementation in [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, numpy guy, answering numpy tags :)

Comment: Quick perusal of Theano docs and it seems you need to construct `x = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False, True, False])()`
`w = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False, False, True])()`and then you can broadcast them to each other. Then I think the rest of your calcs will work.

Comment: Thanks! it works, can I add the code to your answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the the number of rows in `W` can be known in advance, so I'm temporally doing

```
x = tensor.TensorType("float64", [False, False])()
m = 2
w = tensor.as_tensor([[2,2,2],[1,2,3]])
res_list = []
for i in range(m):
    res_list.append(ten.sum((x-w[i,:])**2, axis=1))

z = tensor.stack(res_list)

fn = theano.function([x], z)
print fn([[1,2,3], [2,2,2], [2,3,4]])

# [[ 2.  0.  5.]
#  [ 0.  2.  3.]]
```

Other answers are welcome!