# Calculate Distance between numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two arrays, the first np.array is the points from, and the second np.array are all the distances I need to calculate.

Example:

```
 import numpy as np
 from_array = np.array([(0,1), (1,1), ..., (x,y)])
 to_array = np.array([(5,1), (3,1), ..., (x,y)])
```

What I need to do is take the first entry of the `from_array` and calculate all the distances between `from_array[0]` to all points in to_array, then keep the maximum distance.

So I can brute for this:

```
 def get_distances(from_array, to_array):
     results = []
     distances = []
     for pt in from_array:
        for to in to_array:
            results.append(calc_dist(pt, to))
        distances.append(results)
     return distances
```

But this is slow, I am looking for an optimized way of doing the calculation since I could have thousands of points.

The end goal is to calculate the Hausdorff Distance.

```
fhd = np.mean(np.min(SomeDistanceArray,axis=0))
rhd = np.mean(np.min(SomeDistanceArray,axis=1))
print (max(fhd, rhd))
```

I want to use numpy for this task **only**.
My distance can either be euclidean or square euclidean distance.

So what I am looking help for is an optimized method for calculating the euclidean distance methods for two np.arrays.  It should be noted that array 1 might have more rows than array 2.  Means that the length of the 2D array (x,y) could be comparing 10 row to 30 rows.

Comment: Look into Scipy's cdist.

Comment: I feel like I just answered this [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969013/theano-row-column-wise-subtraction/40969905#40969905)

Comment: Scipy Version 0.19.0 (development version as of Jan2017) has an implementation of ['directed Hausdorff distance'](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff.html#scipy-spatial-distance-directed-hausdorff) you may want to look into. It uses an efficient algorithm (see [paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2015.2408351)) with a close to O(m) runtime (rather than O(m*n)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a NumPy based approach with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = from_array[:,None] - to_array
sq_eucliean_dist = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs)
eucliean_dist = np.sqrt(sq_eucliean_dist)
```

**Note:** If you are later computing `np.mean(np.min(SomeDistanceArray,axis=0))`, you can skip the computation for `eucliean_dist` and directly use `sq_eucliean_dist` as `SomeDistanceArray`, because computing square-root would be pretty expensive.

---

**What does `np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs)` do?** It performs elementwise multiplication between the same array `subs`, i.e. essentially squaring and then does sum-reduction along the last axis, thus losing it in that reduction process.

**So, why not explicitly do the squaring and summing?** Well, the benefit with `np.einsum` is that it does both the squaring and summing in one step, giving us noticeable performance efficiency.

Thus, finally if `from_array` were `(N x 2)` array and `to_array` were `(M x 2)` array, the output from `np.einsum` would be the squared euclidean distances as a 2D array of shape `(N x M)`.
More info on the string notation itself would involve a longer discussion, some of which could be found in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) and the official documentation link posted earlier.

Comment: can you explain the einsum function?  I am not familiar with the notation ijk,ikj.>ij

Comment: @josh1234 Added few comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy only.  So no `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`

First, don't use tuples, use 2xN and 2xM arrays.  Then broadcast.

```
np.linalg.norm(from_array[:,:,None]-to_array[:,None,:], axis=0)
```

If you have an ancient version of numpy without a vecorizable `linalg.norm` (i.e. you're using Abaqus) do this:

```
np.sum((from_array[:,:,None]-to_array[:,None,:])**2, axis=0).__pow__(0.5)
```

Comment: yes no cdist :(. Does this work for uneven arrays?  Say a 30x2 and a 50x2 array?

Comment: Yes, just make sure the common dimension is first, so 2x30 and 2x50, so you can broadcast as above

Comment: So I need to rotate my array from being column X,Y to X,Y as rows:

Comment: sorry, I mean, I need to rotate my array?

Comment: Transpose can be done by just taking the `T` attribute, e.g. `x.T` is the transpose of `x`.

Comment: why doesn't cdist work? was this just a constraint of the question?

Comment: @DanielF cannot believe this is not the a accepted answer

Comment: @DuttaA, `np.einsum` doesn't create a big, memory-hungry intermediate matrix.  If you asked me today I'd give Divakar's answer.  If I could manage to write it faster than he does.